# clang format: how to force a new line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang-format

I use clang-format in visual studio

I have a code like this:

```
matrix << 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8;
```

I want it like this:

```
matrix << 2, 3, 5,
          6, 7, 8;
```

If I break a line manually, I don't want clang-format changes it to one-line and the first number should align with the first number of previous line.

But everytime formatting the cpp file, it becomes one-line like the first code.

How to configure .clang-format file to achieve this?

Comment: why would you want to write `std::cout << 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8;` ? Do you know what the comma operator does?

Comment: `std::cout << 2, 3, 5, // Line break here` will stop clang-format from automagically joining the lines.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number. Sorry. In fact,I want to use this in eigen like this: `mat << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`

Comment: @Eljay But the first number would not align when I type Enter. Can I configure this in visual studio or clang format?

Comment: Did you try to run the program? The comma operator is used to group several expressions together.

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT Yes I have run it. I use this in Eigen, a matrix libarary.